# primefaces : how to disable html escape in <p:inplace>

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, in-place

i'm using primefaces `<p:inplace />` and `<p:editor />` to simulate inline editing in my project.
the problem is that when i'm finished editing the inplace shows me html code as a result.
**Image of the probleme :**
[image]

what i want is some thing like this `<h:outputtext escape="false">` but in `<p:inplace/>`
when i searched i found something about averriding the InplaceRendered and i'm beginner and i really don't know how to do that.
can anyone explane to me how to?
thinks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Editing the PrimeFaces code would be the last option to take.

There was already a similar issue, take a look at this page:

[PrimeFaces - Issue 4330](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4330)

The solution for you could be something like:

```
<p:inplace editor="true">
    <f:facet name="output">
        <h:outputText value="#{yourBean.text}" escape="false" />
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="input">
        <p:inputText value="#{yourBean.text}" />
    </f:facet>
</p:inplace>
```